# Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (butterknife-7.0.1.jar)

Tags: android

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following
>   dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation
>   processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>     - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (butterknife-7.0.1.jar)
>     - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1) Alternatively, set
>   android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath
>   = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

I have given in build.gradle

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
```

and also given dependencies annotationProcessor `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0`

Can any one please help me to solve this?

Comment: It seems that the error is talking about `ButterKnife` annotation processor and not `Dagger`'s.

Comment: ok how to solve this

Comment: Have you tried adding Butterknife's annotation processor? `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:7.0.1'`?

Comment: yes i have mentioned in my module and that module is included in build gradle, can you please me to solve this from 2 days i am not able compile my project

Comment: I don't think you need to set `includeCompileClasspath` because you are adding annotation processor anyways. Make sure you have the latest ButterKnife version, which is `8.8.1` as of now. And make sure you are using it properly, because the binding syntax changed. Check the [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

Comment: i have added it but still same error getting =>in build gradle added   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088597/7915814) answer.

Comment: no sir, its not working same error getting

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this error, I'll try to reproduce it once I'm home, can you share your gradle file?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sos.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true



    }

Comment: }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: is there any way to share my text file???

Comment: You can edit your question and add it, or use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com), but better to add it here in case someone else will see it and help.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UiPpwM87

Comment: I took a look at it, but to be honest I am not sure what's causing the problem. You can delete this dependency and try to build so that you can see if it's actually the reason. Other than that I'm not too sure.

Comment: ok..( sir thank you

Comment: No problem :) good luck!